# Finding an equation for a circle given its center and a point through which it passes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles

No idea how to do this, I used to have these conic shapes committed to memory but I forget them already.

I am supposed to find an equation for the circle that has center $(-1, 4)$ and passes through $(3, -2)$.

I tried graphing it, but it didn't help since the point was not in a straight line with the center and I have no idea what the diameter is.

Comment: You aren't being given "two points" of the circle (that would be insufficient). You are being given the *center* and a point on the circle. Very different things.

Comment: I notice that you say "the point was not in a straight line with the center". But, given any *two* points, there is *some* straight line that joins them. (The straight line may happen to not be parallel to either of the coordinate axes.)

Comment: Perhaps if you understand what a circle is, it may help. A circle is really just all points on the plane equidistant from the center.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Recall the:

**Distance Formula:**

The distance between the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is
$$
D=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2}
$$

**Example:**

The radius of your circle is the distance between the points  $(-1,4)$ and $(3,-2)$. Using the Distance Formula:
$$
D= \sqrt{  \bigl(3-(-1)\bigr)^2 + (-2-4)^2  } 
= \sqrt{  4^2 + (-6)^2  } 
= \sqrt{ 16+36 }
=  \sqrt{ 52 } .
$$

What is the equation of the circle?

It is important to realize   the "equation of the circle" is: a point $(x,y)$ is on the circle if and only if the coordinates of the point $x$ and $y$ satisfy
the equation. So, how to get the equation? What is the relationship between the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of a point on the circle?

Well, let $(x,y)$ be a point on the circle. The big idea is:

$$
\text{The distance from the point }(x,y)\text{  to the center }(-1,4)\text{ is }\sqrt{52}.$$

So, using the distance formula (with $(x_2,y_2)=(x,y)$ and $(x_1,y_1)=(-1,4)$) , it follows that 
$$
\sqrt{52}=\sqrt{\bigl(x-(-1)\bigr)^2 +(y-4)^2}.
$$

Or
$$
52=(x+1)^2 +(y-4)^2.
$$

The shortcut would be to just use the following formula (But it's important to realize why you'd use it and where it comes from):

**Equation of a Circle**

The equation of the circle with center located at $(a,b)$ and with radius $r$ is
$$
r^2=(x-a)^2 +(y-b)^2
$$
Note that the radius *squared* is on the left-hand side of the equation.

---

The following may help: 
 [image]

Comment: Am I supposed to have the distance formula memorized?

Comment: @Jordan Yes. (Not really, if all you want to do is find the equation of the circle. You can use the formula.) But it's really just the Pythagorean Theorem (draw a right triangle with the two points forming its hypotenuse).

Comment: I don't understand how this is the pythagorean theorem. I can work it on on a graph but I don't see how the equation fits that at all or why the answer isn't the square root of 52, not just 52.

Comment: @Jordan I meant the distance formula is an application of the Pythagorean Theorem. Let $c$ be the distance between two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. Call the distance between the $x$-coordinates $a$ and the distance between the $y$ coordinates $b$. Then $c^2=a^2+b^2$. And $a=|x_2-x_1|$, $b=|y_2-y_1|$.

Comment: @Jordan The radius of your circle is $\sqrt{52}$.  The equation of the circle is $52=(x+1)^2+(y-4)^2$.

Comment: Oh because it is radius squared?

Comment: @Jordan Yes! :)

Comment: I understand this now but I will forget it all before I need to actually use it again. I am trying to remember when we use circles in calculus and I don't think it is until optimization problems, so I doubt I can remember this for that long.

Answer (score 3):

The equation of a circle with center $(a,b)$ and radius $r$ is
$$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2.$$

You know the center. You also know one point *on* the circle. The radius is the distance from the center of the circle to any one point on the circle.

So find the distance between $(-1,4)$ and $(3,-2)$ to get the radius. Then use the radius and the center to get the equation.

The diameter is, of course, twice the radius, but is irrelevant here.

Comment: I don't know how to find the difference between two points on a graph.

Comment: @Jordan: The **distance** between two points (which in this case, are *not* both "on a graph"), not the **difference**. I suspect you do know it, you just don't remember it or haven't made the connections. In any case, [Wikipedia has the formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Two_dimensions)

Answer (score 2):

In general a circle with center $(h,k)$ and radius $r$ can be expressed as:

$$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$$

In the case of our questions, you have $(h,k)=(-1,4)$ in the above equation. You can then substitute $(-3,2)$ for $(x,y)$ to find $r$.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should know (or look up in your textbook) that a circle is described by the equation  $(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 = r^2$ where $(x_0, y_0)$ is the center and $r$ is the radius.  So you see your circle should be $(x +1)^2 + (y - 4)^2 = r^2$.  The only thing missing is $r^2$.  But the problem tells you (3, -2) is a point on the circle.  So plugging this into your equation, you will find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a circle with center $(a,b)$ and radius $r$ is
$$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2.$$

Because the center is $(a,b)=(-1,4)$ so $a=-1,b=4$. You also know one point *on* the circle. The radius is the distance from the center of the circle to any one point on the circle.
The distance between $(-1,4)$ and $(3,-2)$ is $r=\sqrt52$ or $r^2=52$. Then use the radius and the center to get the equation.

$$(x+1)^2 + (y-4)^2 = 52$$

Answer (score 0):

The smallest circle passing through those points  would be the circle with a diameter from $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$.    It therefore has a radius of $\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$ with a center of $(\frac12,\frac12)$.   So,     $(x - \frac{1}{2})^2 + (y - \frac12)^2 = \frac12$  would satisfy all conditions.

Any radius smaller than that could not include the two poinst and anything larger than that would not fit the problem.

Answer (score -1):

1 find equation of the circle passing through (1,0) and (0,1) and having the smallest possible radius .
2  show that cot 15/2 degree = √2+√3+√4+√6 .